# Specify the type "mode" for defcustom?

Tags: customization

Is it possible to specify that a defcustom can only take the value of a mode?

More specifically, I've got a variable that's a map from major modes to lists of strings, and I wants users to be able to configure this map. So conceptually I want something like this:

`(defcustom my-type-map
 :type '(alist :key-type 'mode :value-type '(repeat string)))`

Is this possible, or do I just need to use documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since major modes happen to be functions, you can use the `function` type to allow completion of functions.  There is the composite type `restricted-sexp` which allows you to use a predicate to allow even more specific types, however it wouldn't make much sense to use it since there is no predicate or way to determine whether a function is a major mode (despite the convention of them ending in "-mode" it could very well be a minor mode).

Therefore I'd recommend going for functions and adding a descriptive docstring instead.